Issue with collecting state tomography data
I am having a problem with collecting state tomography data. When I am running the below code, I get the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'num_qubits'
# Initializing the simulator
backend = AerSimulator()

# This is the function to generate a random circuit
def generate_random_circuit(num_qubits, depth):
    return random_circuit(num_qubits, depth, measure=True)

# This is the function to execute the circuit and get results
def execute_circuit(circuit):
    compiled_circuit = transpile(circuit, backend)
    result = backend.run(compiled_circuit, shots=1024).result()
    return result.get_counts()

# This is the dummy function to collect tomography data.
def collect_tomography_data(circuit, qubits):
    # Placeholder function to collect tomography data
    # Replace this with actual tomography data collection
    print(f"Collecting tomography data for qubits: {qubits}")
    # Example: Print circuit for which tomography data is being collected
    print(circuit.draw(output='text'))
    # Returning dummy data for the sake of example
    return {qubit: np.random.rand() for qubit in qubits}


# This real data collection function is still a work in progress.
def collect_tomography_data(circuit, qubits):
    """
    Perform quantum state tomography on the specified qubits of the given circuit.

    Args:
        circuit (QuantumCircuit): The quantum circuit on which tomography is to be performed.
        qubits (list): The qubits on which tomography data is collected.

    Returns:
        dict: A dictionary of tomography data (probabilities or state information).
    """
    # Use the Aer simulator for statevector-based simulation
    simulator = AerSimulator()

    # Append tomography measurements to the circuit
    tomography = StateTomography(circuit)

    # Transpile the circuit to make it compatible with the simulator
    transpiled_circuit = transpile(tomography.circuits(), simulator)

    # Run the simulation
    storage = StateTomography(transpiled_circuit)
    storage = storage.run(backend, seed_simulation=100).block_for_results()

    for result in storage.analysis_results():
      print(result)
    result = backend.run(transpiled_circuit, shots=1024).result()


    # Reconstruct the state from tomography data
    tomography_data = tomography.fit(result)

    # Simplified output: fidelity and probability information (can expand as needed)
    return tomography_data.data()

# Parameters that can be manually adjusted
num_qubits = 6  # 3 qubits + 1 measurement qubit (can be adjusted as needed)
max_depth = 3 # Maximum circuit depth
cycles = 5 # This is the maximum number of cycles.

# Initializing list to store tomography data
tomography_data = None

# Main loop
depth = 1
for cycle in range(cycles):
    print(f"Starting cycle {cycle + 1}")

    # Generating and executing a random circuit
    circuit = generate_random_circuit(num_qubits, depth)
    counts = execute_circuit(circuit)

    # Measuring the zeroth qubit
    zeroth_qubit_down_count = 0
    for outcome in counts:
        if outcome[0] == '0':  # Checking if the first bit (zeroth qubit) is down
            zeroth_qubit_down_count += counts[outcome]

    # Conditional process based on the zeroth qubit's measurement state per cycle
    if zeroth_qubit_down_count > 0:
        print("Zeroth qubit is down")

        # Increasing the depth for the next circuit based on the state of the 0th qubit
        depth = min(depth + 1, max_depth)
    else:
        # Collecting tomography data for the remaining qubits before stopping as 0th qubit is in the up state
        tomography_data = collect_tomography_data(circuit, range(1, num_qubits)) # Replace 6 with num_qubits

        # Stopping the procedure if the zeroth qubit is up (printing message)
        print("Zeroth qubit is up, stopping the procedure.")
        break

    # Visualizing the circuit
    print(circuit.draw(output='text'))

    print(f"Cycle {cycle + 1} completed. Zeroth qubit state: {'down' if zeroth_qubit_down_count > 0 else 'up'}")
    print("-" * 50)


# If the maximum number of cycles is reached without the zeroth qubit being up, collect tomography data. Data is also collected otherwise.
if cycle == cycles - 1 and zeroth_qubit_down_count > 0:
    print("Maximum number of cycles reached. Collecting tomography data for remaining qubits.")
    tomography_data = collect_tomography_data(circuit, range(1, num_qubits)) # Replace 6 with num_qubits

print(f"Procedure completed. Ended at cycle {cycle + 1} with zeroth qubit state: {'down' if zeroth_qubit_down_count > 0 else 'up'}")

# Displaying collected tomography data if available (states of the qubits besides the 0th qubit) for the opposite of the above-noted case.
if tomography_data is not None:
    print("\nTomography Data Collected at the end:")
    print(tomography_data)
else:
    print("No tomography data collected as the zeroth qubit never went up.")



related post.
